how to change the item placement orientation in LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid? can we specify the row and column where item needs to be placed?
I am using LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid to show a list where items have been placed with different width and same height. I achieved it using below mentioned code.
BY default items placed row by row, e.g. first item placed in first row and then second item is in second row until last row and then for next item it places the item again in first row and second column.
Instead what I want is to place the item in first row until all columns of first row is filled and then move to second row. Basically I want to customize the orientation, Can we achieve that and if yes how  can we do that. Any guidance is appreciated.
Did not find any direct option to do that.
Expectation is to show the data in LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid, items should be placed row by row not by coulmn.


What I want is to place the item in first row until all columns of first row is filled.

A LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid is, as the name indicates, a horizontally scrolling lazy grid. Lazy indicates that new items are loaded dynamically as you scroll horizontally. The grid grows alongside the horizontal axis-
This means that the first row never is "full" in that sense, the first row will be as wide as it needs to be until all items are placed. If we defined a certain width per row, then Jetpack Compose would have to render all items eagerly in order to determine the placement, which defies the concept of a lazy Composable.
To get a lazy loading functionality, Jetpack Compose will distribute the items one after each other across the rows. Each item is placed into the row that currently has the smallest width as you scroll.
So unfortunately, you will not get your desired functionality using a LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid. I would recommend that you reconsider your requirements. You could use a FlowRow to make the items populate row per row, but then you would loose the ability to scroll horizontally.

If you have many items to display, consider using the lazy variant of FlowRow.

Thanks for the suggestion, let me try FlowRow.

If you have many items to display, consider using the lazy variant of FlowRow, see the link in my edited answer. If this answer resolves your question, please consider marking it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

lazy variant of FlowRow will allow me to scroll the list horizontally?

@NamitaSurana Unfortunately not. It will only display a "show more" button. By clicking it, you can always display the next few items in the FlowRow.
